# Scroll Inputfields into view when virtual windows 10 keyboard is present

Tags: javascript, windows, angular, input, keyboard

I'm actually creating a webapp with angular5. The app should be used on tablets, running windows 10. This webapp needs to run in Firefox or internet explorer, edge isn't possible due to some infrastructural reasons.

The app has some input fields. If a input field is in the area of the virtual keyboard, the keyboard does hide it when it appears on clicking in the field.
In Edge now the input field scrolls into view, so you can see what you type. But in Firefox and Internet Explorer it does not.

Has someone an idea, how i can force Firefox and Internet Explorer also to scroll the input fields into view by js/css/html?